# Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' while building jar file from android project

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Unable to build library project as jar.

Updated to the latest android studio and gradle versions

```
task makeJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('build/outputs/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename ('classes.jar', 'myLib.jar')//you can change this directory where you want to copy your .jar
}

task clearJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'build/libs/myLib.jar'
}

makeJar.dependsOn(clearJar,build)

gradlew makeJar
```

Already observed package id 'platform-tools' in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools'. Skipping duplicate at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools.old923420354'
cvc-pattern-valid: Value '' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+' for type 'idType'.:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 145; columnNumber: 348; cvc-pattern-valid: Value '' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+' for type 'idType'.

cvc-type.3.1.3: The value '' of element 'id' is not valid.:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 145; columnNumber: 348; cvc-type.3.1.3: The value '' of element 'id' is not valid.

*****> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.

> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.*****

Answer (score 0):

> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin FAILED FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
>
> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.

It seems like you didn't install the JDK. If you install JDK from [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-downloads-5295953.html), it may works.

Comment: I have already installed jdk and it was present in the same folder in which error is specifiying.

Comment: Then try changing java version of the gradle JVM in the setting. Find 'Gradle JVM' (on the search bar) or go to the Settings/Preferences dialog (Ctrl+Alt+S), go to Build, Execution, Deployment| Gradle then ensure that proper version of JDK is selected.